# MySQL: fetching only one row per person which has highest value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores top three high scores of each player. Example data is:

```
id     player_id     score        score_date
------------------------------------------------------
1      100           1100         2015-10-10
2      101           1750         2015-10-07
3      100           3200         2015-10-10
4      102           4100         2015-10-10
5      101           3000         2015-10-01
```

How can I write a query that will fetch me the highest score record of the each player for a particular date? Say my date is `2015-10-10`, the result I want is:

```
player_id     score        date
------------------------------------------------------
100           3200         2015-10-10
102           4100         2015-10-10
```

If you notice, the `player 100` has two scores on the said date. I tried:

```
select * from player
where  date(score_date) = date('2015-10-10')
group by player_id
```

But it gave me `1100` as score for `player 100`, but correct value is `3200`. I also tried adding `ORDER by score DESC limit 1` to end of the above query but then the results were just weird...

I hope the MySQL gurus in SO will take mercy on me and help...

Answer (score 2):

```
select player_id, MAX(score), score_date from player
where  date(score_date) = date('2015-10-10')
group by player_id
```

Comment: This is corrent except for selecting the id field, since it won't return the correct one. But seeing it that the OP does not need it, he'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you, that works :) Unfortunately I framed my question incorrectly and need to do something more...so let me post that as a different question.

Comment: Just for interest's sake, can you post a link here to the new question?